# Замена ссылок на слово+ссылка

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Идея такая, в ckeditor отправляется различный текст. Если есть "голые" ссылки вида:

```
https://domen.ru/43654766587878787?dlinnaya+ssylka
```

то меняем их на слово "ссылка" и саму ссылку вида:

```
<a href="https://link.ru/43654766587878787?dlinnaya+ssylka" class="link" target="_blank">ссылка</a>
```

с этой задачей я справился, НО у меня в ckeditor так же используется подсветка синтаксиса (вставка кода) вообщем моя замена меняет ссылки и в куске кода.
Этот код начинается с

```
<pre><code class="...
```

и заканчивается соответственно:

```
<code><pre>
```

Нужно дописать регулярное выражение, чтобы была проверка на отсутствие вначале и в конце этих вставок. То есть внутри code ничего не меняем, остальное проверяем. Как я не пытался, у меня не вышло.
Вот моя замена ссылок:

```
$message = preg_replace('@((https?://)?([-\\w]+\\.[-\\w\\.]+)+\\w(:\\d+)?(/([-\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)*)@', '<a href="http://$1" class="link" target="_blank">ссылка</a>', $message);
```

Это сообщение приходит на вебсокет, обрабатывается, сохраняется в БД и отправляется красивый текст обратно в окно клиенту.

Comment: Как вариант, пока сделал обработку ссылки ДО отправки на сервер с помощью JS. Все работает, но хотелось бы увидеть вариант на php.

Answer (score 1):

> *Нужно дописать регулярное выражение, чтобы была проверка на отсутствие вначале и в конце этих вставок. То есть внутри code ничего не меняем, остальное проверяем*

Можно конечно ещё подумать над составлением шаблона, но можно пойти и не много другим путём:

```
$str = '
    <a href="#">Линк</a> Текст 1
    https://domen.ru/43654766587878787?dlinnaya+ssylka Текст 2
    <pre><code>
    https://domen.ru/43654766587878787?dlinnaya+ssylka
    <a href="#">Линк</a>
    </code></pre>
';
```

Сначала найти и сохранить в переменную весь блок `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`

```
preg_match('~<pre><code[^>]*>.+?</code></pre>~s', $str, $code);
```

Потом произвести замену всех ссылок *(в том числе и ссылок внутри тега `<a>`)*

```
$str = preg_replace('~https?://\S+|<a[^>]*>.+?</a>~', 'Ссылка', $str);
```

И напоследок заменить блок `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` на ранее сохранённый его аналог

```
$str = preg_replace('~<pre><code[^>]*>.+?</code></pre>~s', $code[0], $str);

echo $str;
```

Результат:

```
Ссылка Текст 1
Ссылка Текст 2
<pre><code>
https://domen.ru/43654766587878787?dlinnaya+ssylka
<a href="#">Линк</a>
</code></pre>
```

Comment: интересное решение, но если в сообщении несколько отдельных кусков кода то заменяет все на одну и ту же ссылку.
у меня вчера была аналогичная мысль, но я хотел делить сообщение на массивы <code> и просто текст, затем где нет <code> заменять ссылки если есть. пока не пробовал